# Pulling Contentful data using VueJS and Nuxt.JS

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, contentful

Okay, I want to pull data (existing one) from Contentful using VueJS.

I'm no developer so I don't really understand how this fully works, I was able to follow through half-way of [their tutorial](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/javascript/tutorials/integrate-contentful-with-vue-and-nuxt/), but as I already have my space and data, I got stuck, the tutorial sticks to a blog-type and never really mentioned anything how I can pull a data with different structure.

Based on the tutorial, I have to create a .contentful.json containing

```
{
  "CTF_PERSON_ID": "15jwOBqpxqSAOy2eOO4S0m",
  "CTF_BLOG_POST_TYPE_ID": "blogPost",
  "CTF_SPACE_ID": "YOUR_SPACE_ID",
  "CTF_CDA_ACCESS_TOKEN": "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
}
```

They didn't mention how I can pull other data than what they had provided as a template.

What I want to know:
1. If I have my own space, not from the template, how or where can I find something similar to "CTF_PERSON_ID" and "CTF_BLOG_POST_TYPE_ID".

Answer (score 1):

Are you using nuxt or "Vanilla Vue"? These id's you mention are read in the `nuxt.config.js` file which is the main configuration file for nuxt. Nuxt run's javascript on the server and client side and that's why it needs to know what the configuration parameters are.

```
// ./nuxt.config.js
const config = require('./.contentful.json')

module.exports = {
  // ...
  env: {
    CTF_SPACE_ID: config.CTF_SPACE_ID,
    CTF_CDA_ACCESS_TOKEN: config.CTF_CDA_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    CTF_PERSON_ID: config.CTF_PERSON_ID,
    CTF_BLOG_POST_TYPE_ID: config.CTF_BLOG_POST_TYPE_ID
  }
  // ...
}
```

The `env` property in the nuxt.config object is read in the page components (`pages/index.vue` or `pages/blog/index.vue`).

```
const client = createClient()
export default {
  asyncData ({ env, params }) {
    return client.getEntries({
      'content_type': env.CTF_BLOG_POST_TYPE_ID,
      order: '-sys.createdAt'
    }).then(entries => {
      return {
        posts: entries.items
      }
    })
  },
  components: {
    ArticlePreview,
    Navigation
  }
}
```

If you have different structures you can add a new content type id in your configuration file (`.contentful.json`) and add it to `env` in `nuxt.config.js` (this could be restructured to avoid the duplication, but that's a different topic) and then access it in the page components via `env` to query the data using `getEntries`.

Hope that helps. :)